# CahePHP 2.x adding async to script tag

Tags: cakephp

How could I print async in the script tag in CakePHP 2.4.4?
I have tried with

```
echo $this->Html->script('script', array('inline' => true, 'async' => true));
```

but it seems that it's not the right way.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` is not a known minimized attribute (see [**`Helper::$_minimizedAttributes`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.4/lib/Cake/View/Helper.php#L146)), so you either have to pass the string `async` as the value, ie

```
'async' => 'async'
```

or add `async` to the list of minimized attributes so that CakePHP can also handle the value of `true` properly.

The latter can be done using the [**`configFile` option**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-HtmlHelper.html#___construct) or the [**`HtmlHelper::loadConfig()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3aloadConfig) method to load a config file containing an array of minimized attributes.

```
$config = array('minimizedAttributes' => array('async'));
```

By default both of this will leave you with a tag like `<script ... async='async'>`. If you want shorthand [**boolean attributes**](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#boolean-attributes), then you'll have to change the `minimizedAttributeFormat` option too, to something like `'%s'`.